# Android - Constructor is undefined

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send a notification in an thread, but it somehow does not work.

```
public void start_progressbar(View v) {

    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,
            "Sending Notification", "Working... ", true, false);

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                notification();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                final String ERROR = e.toString();
                Log.e(TAG + "He's dead Jim!!", "" + e);
            }
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        private void notification() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Notification not = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New Event")
            .setContentText("Monday 12. 11. 2014 meeting")
            .build();
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What does not work? Sending the notification or processing the sent notification? Anything in the log file?

Answer (score 4):

In an inner class, use `OuterClassName.this` to refer to the outer class instance. `this` alone refers to the inner class instance i.e. the anonymous `Thread` subclass in your case.

Comment: NB this problem (`this` vs inner classes) occurs in many situations and is quite hard to spot... I usually have it when using `.get()`, `.equals()` and other methods accepting `Object` as param (yeah, it's the dreaded backward compatibility of the API) and moving code to-and-fro main code vs inner methods; awfully easy to forget about having to update `this` scope due to scope change there; also, it's kind of strange that compilers I know of don't warn of this type of errors.